# MSBuild copy files to a single folder without file hierarchy

Tags: tfs, msbuild

IN TFS 2017 on-premises site, I've put together a TFS build that generates several database builds and SSIS package builds.  it produces the desired dacpac and ispac files.  However, when created, these files are placed in a hierarchy, based on the particular project structure.  It looks something like this:

```
Database1
    \bin
        \Release
            \database1.dacpac
Database2
    \bin
        \Release
            \database2.dacpac
ssisPackage
    \bin
        \Development
            \ssispackage.ispac
```

I would like to copy all of these files (*.dacpac and *.ispac) to a single 
directory (flattened) when pushing them out to my team.  However, the Copy Files task is copying them and preserving the folder structure.

The Contents block of the "Copy Files" task is:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*.dacpac
**\bin\Development\*.ispac
```

and the Target Folder is

```
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

Is there a way to move this files to the target folder without the folder hierarchy, resulting in:

```
OutputFolder
    \database1.dacpac
    \database2.dacpac
    \ssispackage.ispac
```

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Just `<Copy Files=@(SourceFiles) DestinationFolder=$(TargetDir)/>` in msbuild ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Create a bat file with code below and add to your project, then check into source control (%1 means first argument, %2 means second argument)

Code:

```
pushd %1
       for /r %%a in (*.pdb) do (
         copy "%%a" %2
       )
       popd
```

2. Add Command Line build step to your build definition

[image]

Note: This code is used to copy pdb files, you need to modify it per to requirements.

Comment: excellent approach.  I hadn't thought of stepping to a batch file to gather this.  My view was too myopic I guess.  but this did the job.